# Wait for other processes

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have to wait for multiple background process before doing other, I am looking for and trying to do something with this, but I can't. Here is the code. I commented the parts to explain what I want to reach. I could do it with completion handler but this function is called for a few times, depending on number of photos.

```
func prepareArray(stext: NSMutableAttributedString, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
    self.finalForUpload = [String]()
    var attributedArray = [AnyObject]()
    var lastRng = 0
    let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0,stext.length)
    stext.enumerateAttributesInRange(range, options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), usingBlock: {(dic: [String:AnyObject]?, range :NSRange!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


        let attachement = dic as NSDictionary!
        attachement.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock({ (key:AnyObject?, obj:AnyObject?, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


            let stri = key as! NSString!
            if stri == "NSAttachment"{
                let att:NSTextAttachment = obj as! NSTextAttachment
                if att.image != nil{
                    print("range location: \(range.location)")
                    if range.location != lastRng {
                        attributedArray.append(stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(lastRng, range.location-lastRng)))
                        lastRng = range.length
                    }
                    let im:UIImage = att.image!
                    self.httpManager.uploadPhoto(im, completionHandler: { (imgName) -> Void in
                        let imName = imgName.characters.dropFirst()
                        let imageName = String(imName.dropLast())
                        //WAIT FOR THIS
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            print("append")
                            //stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(range)
                            attributedArray.append(imageName)
                            lastRng = range.location
                        })
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    })
    //BEFORE DOING THIS
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if lastRng == 0 && attributedArray.count < 1{
            attributedArray.append(stext)
        } else {
            attributedArray.append(stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(lastRng, stext.length-lastRng)))
        }
        for var i = 0; i<attributedArray.count; i++ {
            print("\n \n \(i) :     \(attributedArray[i])")
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main queue is a serial queue, meaning that it executes on block at a time in first-in-first-out order.  All of the dispatches in the enumerate should be done before the one at the bottom is run.

EDIT: just noticed that you async in a completion handler.

One simple thing to do is to just count down (because you know how many there are).

Just add `var expectedCompletions = attachement.count` before the enumerate and then count them down (`expectedCompletions--`) inside the block.  When it gets to 0, run the code at the end.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you async in a completion handler.  Added a simple thing to try.

Comment: It's not safe to access a variable from different threads without synchronisation.

Comment: You initialize before you start the blocks. You decrement only in the main queue, which is serialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`dispatch_group` methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19).

However I would recommend using something like [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/) or similar which gives you a much nicer way of controlling dependencies of multiple async blocks.

Here is your code using `dispatch_group` methods:

```
func prepareArray(stext: NSMutableAttributedString, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
    // create the dispatch group
    dispatch_group_t aGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    self.finalForUpload = [String]()
    var attributedArray = [AnyObject]()
    var lastRng = 0
    let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0,stext.length)
    stext.enumerateAttributesInRange(range, options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), usingBlock: {(dic: [String:AnyObject]?, range :NSRange!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


        let attachement = dic as NSDictionary!
        attachement.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock({ (key:AnyObject?, obj:AnyObject?, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


            let stri = key as! NSString!
            if stri == "NSAttachment"{
                let att:NSTextAttachment = obj as! NSTextAttachment
                if att.image != nil{
                    print("range location: \(range.location)")
                    if range.location != lastRng {
                        attributedArray.append(stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(lastRng, range.location-lastRng)))
                        lastRng = range.length
                    }
                    let im:UIImage = att.image!

                    // use dispatch_group to coordinate.
                    // must call before uploadPhoto as we don't know how long it will take
                    dispatch_group_enter(aGroup);

                    self.httpManager.uploadPhoto(im, completionHandler: { (imgName) -> Void in
                        let imName = imgName.characters.dropFirst()
                        let imageName = String(imName.dropLast())

                        dispatch_async(aGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            print("append")
                            //stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(range)
                            attributedArray.append(imageName)
                            lastRng = range.location

                            // indicate block has completed (reduced group count)
                            dispatch_group_leave(aGroup);
                        })
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    })

    // wait for all items in group to finish before running this block
    dispatch_group_notify(aGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if lastRng == 0 && attributedArray.count < 1{
            attributedArray.append(stext)
        } else {
            attributedArray.append(stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(lastRng, stext.length-lastRng)))
        }
        for var i = 0; i<attributedArray.count; i++ {
            print("\n \n \(i) :     \(attributedArray[i])")
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: It's preferable to use `dispatch_group_nofity` instead `dispatch_group_wait` since this will not block the calling thread.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you're right. Code changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to wait for multiple background process before doing other

You should really look at using `NSOperationQueue` for this requirement as it allows you to configure dependencies between all of the registered operations. In this way you could configure and add a number of downloads and then configure a post download action which is dependent on all of those downloads. The operation queue will deal with starting that operation when all others are complete.

The operations also give you a nice way to cancel the pending uploads / downloads if you don't need them any more.

You could alternatively look at using `dispatch_group`s to manage this. It's harder to ensure that what you've done is entirely correct.